# ABOUT SCOPE_IDENTITY

Tags: sql-server

SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY is always resulting id=1,
what i have done wrong?
how to get  the currentid of the inserted element.

Comment: It would probably help to show us your code.

Answer (score 1):

A good article on the different methods to 
[retrieve the last inserted](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/).

Answer (score 1):

SCOPE_IDENTITY does indeed return the identity column of the last inserted row in the scope you are in.

It can be messed up by a few things, within the same scope. In that case `IDENT_CURRENT('myTable')` will be better.

If not you'll want to post more code. SCOPE_IDENTITY does work as you think, so the problem is likely elsewhere.

Comment: How can `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` be messed up by triggers? I thought that was its advantage over `@@IDENTITY`.

Comment: It shouldn't, but can in some cases. http://cgaskell.wordpress.com/2006/11/15/using-identity-vs-scope_identity-and-further-implications-with-triggers/

Comment: Have you verified this for yourself? The comment by angeliii seems to imply some user error on the part of the blog author.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing it within the same trasaction? Is the identity actually being incremented in the Database?

Comment: yes,the identity is actually being incremented in the Database

Answer (score 0):

Is the column set as Is Identity=Yes?